Make Python script always running/active?
I'm unexperienced in those kinds of tasks. I made a Python script that thought Selenium opened a website and clicked a button via the CSS Selector.
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver= webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("webpage")
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div.ml12:nth-child(1) > a:nth-child(1)").click()

This button pops up every 10 minutes on the website, so I would like it to be automatic in order to avoid me clicking it every time.
Is there a way to keep the script running/active when the window is open?
I didn't find anything that could help me to fix the problem.

you can always put find_element and click in while True: to repeat it all the time. If you add time.sleep(...10min...) then it will sleep 10 minutes before it click again.

You can use time and while loop to make it run the whole time, and check every 10 minutes if there is a button to click with that CSS selector.
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import time

driver= webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("webpage")

# Make the program run continuously
while True:
    try:
        driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div.ml12:nth-child(1) > a:nth-child(1)").click()
        # Wait e.g. 10 minutes (you can adjust the time as you want)
        time.sleep(600)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print("Element not found.")
        break
    

